# Where is my password stored on Windows 7?

Tags: passwords, windows

Is there a specific location where the passwords are stored ?

Are they salted ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally this is  `c:\windows\system32\config\SAM`  The passwords can be either LANMAN or NTLM. LANMAN does not use a salt and is extremely weak. On Windows XP and earlier LANMAN hashes are enabled by default. These do not use salting and are extremely easy to crack or lookup in a rainbow table. They should be disabled so the system uses NTLM hashes (which are salted). As of Windows Vista NTLM is enabled by default.